# Create angular-cli app without default packages for tooling

Tags: angular, angular-cli

While creating an angular app with @angular/cli I found, several other packages are getting installed such as: **karma, protractor, jasmine etc.**

Since I am a beginner with angular I will not need these extra packages as of now.
In future may be I will require them or may be a different combination of them but surely not as of now.

So how do I avoid installing all these extra tooling packages and just install essentials for learning Angular?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new) for @angular/cli state that you can use the `minimal` flag when running `ng new`, like so:

```
ng new --minimal [name]
```

This will exclude both karma and protractor tests and does not include the corresponding NPM packages.

If you want to explore the output of @angular/cli a little more, you might benefit from using the `--skip-install` flag - This will just generate the files but will not download and install all the packages. You could inspect the `package.json` file to see the dependencies that have been added, etc, just to get a feel for what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

The Angular CLI makes it easy to start small and gradually add dependencies as needed.

**Step 1**

```
ng new simple-app --minimal --skip-tests --skip-install --dry-run
```

Running this command will show you a list of files that would be created in a new Angular app called `simple-app`.

[angular-minimal-dry-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1tD.png)

**Step 2**

```
ng new simple-app --minimal --skip-tests --skip-install
```

Now, rerun the command without the `--dry-run` option, and you'll have a very minimal Angular app to work with. No tests, and very few dependencies.

**Step 3**

```
npm install
```

After you've had time to examine the files that were created, you'll need to run `npm install` from within your project directory to install the required dependencies.

**Step 4**

```
ng build
```

At this point, you'll have a ready-to-run app with a fairly minimal set of dependencies.