# Which packages in official Angular boilerplate are really needed and why?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, boilerplate

My project has a TypeScript/Express server, and I want to add Angular to the same project.

I completed the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), so I understand the basics.

Most people will just use the official Angular "boilerplate" - [`ng new appname`](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). But I want to know *the minimum set of packages* to add to `package.json`, and why.

I assume some packages are unnecessary, and were added to make it easier for devs to learn Angular - I don't want these.

The CLI adds these as `dependencies`:

```
@angular/animations
@angular/common
@angular/compiler
@angular/core
@angular/forms
@angular/platform-browser
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
@angular/router
core-js
rxjs
tslib
zone.js
```

And these as `devDependencies`:

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular
@angular/cli
@angular/compiler-cli
@angular/language-service
codelyzer
jasmine-core                     // I assume this is for unit testing
jasmine-spec-reporter            // I assume this is for unit testing
karma
karma-chrome-launcher
karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter
karma-jasmine
karma-jasmine-html-reporter
protractor                       // I assume this is for integration testing
ts-node
```

Which of these are actually needed? (or put another way: which of them can I remove?)

Comment: Explain the downvote. This is a good question. Most devs just use the boilerplate without caring about the details. I can't build a professional system that way, I need to know why all its bits are needed.

Comment: Unnecessary tags, too many questions in one question...

Comment: @MaihanNijat These are the questions every professional dev will ask when using an **official**  "boilerplate". Should I ask 20 separate questions for the same topic?

Comment: I understand... I hope you get your answer.

Comment: @MaihanNijat Thanks, me too! :)

Comment: _I test my server with Jest. Can I use it instead of Jasmine and Karma and Protractor_ a professional dev would know that this question makes no sense.

Comment: _An Angular project is compiled and deployed as a set of static files... so I thought everything would be in devDependencies. Why are there packages in dependencies_ you might want to read about the conceptual difference of these two

Comment: Most of the packages in `dependencies` are required. You could trim a couple from angular depending on your needs. A lot in `devDependencies` is optional, you should be able to answer what you need with some effort by reading about the different modules included in there.

Comment: @JotaToledo A professional would know not to insult others. And by the way, I'm new to the stack so I don't know the answers to that... and I'm humble enough to ask.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo And my question is valid. I know the difference between the two. But upon deployment, only the dev dependencies are needed. And from what I understand about angular, there will be no "action" on the server.... so why are packages in deps instead of all in devdeps? See, reasonable question. If you don't feel like being helpful, why are you here?

Comment: Didn't commented with the intention to offend or similar. I actually hinted some answers at your questions. _But upon deployment, only the dev dependencies are needed_ I dont know where you got that from, but its wrong. There is both a conceptual and functional difference in relation to `dependencies` and `devDependencies` that you could easily find in SO. Other than that, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155209/create-angular-cli-app-without-default-packages-for-tooling

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Some of the stuff in that link was helpful, thanks. And my misunderstanding is because from what I understood from the official angular tutorials, was that it compiles - at development time - to a set of static files, which are uploaded to a server. So I could not (and still don't) understand why I need dev dependencies at runtime - I will do more digging.

Comment: _why I need dev dependencies_ Do you mean `devDependencies`? If thats the case, then no, they arent required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/5394220

Comment: Sorry no I mean `dependencies`. I'm gonna ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `dependencies`. From what I can tell, in this list nothing is optional.

**@angular/animations**
For animations. Without animations, web page transitions can seem abrupt and jarring. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

**@angular/common**
**@angular/compiler**
**@angular/core**
All three are core library.

**@angular/forms**
Supports HTML forms, specifically bindings.

**@angular/platform-browser**
Supports delivery of Angular apps on different supported browsers. [Docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser)

**@angular/platform-browser-dynamic**
Knows how to bootstrap the application on specific browser. [Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407652/1834562)

**@angular/router**
Supports routing.

**core-js**
Modular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for ECMAScript 5, ECMAScript 6. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js)

**rxjs**
Supports events and observables.

**tslib**
This is a runtime library for TypeScript that contains all of the TypeScript helper functions. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib)

**zone.js**
The main purpose of using zonejs in angular2 is to know when to render. [Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902572/what-is-the-use-of-zone-js-in-angular-2)

> `devDependencies`.

**@angular-devkit/build-angular**
Probably required by angular-cli to build.

**@angular/cli**
**@angular/compiler-cli**
Both are required for angular-cli to work correctly.

**@angular/language-service**
The Angular Language Service is a way to get completions, errors, hints, and navigation inside your Angular templates. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/language-service)

**codelyzer**
Static analysis for Angular projects. [Docs](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer)

**jasmine-core**
**jasmine-spec-reporter**
Used for unit-testing and generating coverage report respectively.

**karma**
**karma-chrome-launcher**
**karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter**
**karma-jasmine**
**karma-jasmine-html-reporter**
Karma is a test runner. Jasmine uses this. The reporters are used to generate coverage.

**protractor**
Used for end-to-end testing.

**ts-node**
Typescript for NodeJs.

> To your original question, I wouldn't recommend to remove anything because as you can see, each of them are doing something specific which you don't want to loose while development. My small angular app is about 500Mb, but it doesn't matter because once I do `ng build`, it gets compiled to 20Mb.
>
> Additionally as pointed in [linked SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47223544/1834562), you can use `ng new --minimal [name]` to generate a minimal list of packages absolutely required to run your application.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer